# Looking for suitable DataBound control to implement questions page

Tags: c#, asp.net, databound-controls

I looking forward to find a suitable asp.net DataBound control (C#) to implement in my application.

I wanted to create a exam page where each page show 10 questions, each question got a Label control and a radiobutton control to display the choices, the data to be bind into the DataBound control might be having multiple rows where each rows represent each question.

I found that DetailView control was quite suit with my requirement but I not able to set the page size.

Please help to give some suggestion and advises, thank you in advanced.

Comment: what do you mean by "set the page size" ?

Comment: DetailsView is used for displaying only one database item, and i assume each question will be a database item.

Comment: I want to display 10 items in a page

Comment: I updated my reply for pagination requirement.

Comment: You should accept answers to questions you previously asked so more people will want to help you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a DataList or a ListView, because it will allow you to enter a template for each item. The reason I would choose these over a repeater is because you can use data keys, which will probably come in handy.

Here's a simple example of how you could implement a list of questions:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="QuestionID" ...>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question")%>' />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="Yes" GroupName="QuestionAnswer" ... />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="No" GroupName="QuestionAnswer" ... />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to you to use the Repeater control since you can customize it's design very easily to suit your needs.

Here are two tutorials on how to use it:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

http://www.learn-asp.net/asptutorials/Repeater.aspx

**Update:**

Repeater doesn't have pagination included so you would have to add it:

http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2009/03/25/adding-paging-repeater/

Other option would be to just use a GridView which has pagination included.